# How to prove $P(A|B) = \sum_{i=1}{n} P(A|BH_i) P(H_i|B)$ if I know that $H_1, \ldots ,H_n$ is a complete system of events and $P(B)>0$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How to prove $$P(A|B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A|BH_i) P(H_i|B)$$ if I know that $H_1, \ldots ,H_n$  is a complete system of events and $P(B)>0$.  I know that when I have independent events $P(H_1,...,H_n)=P(H_1) \cdot P(H_2) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(H_n)$ and because of the fact this is a complete system  of events $H_1 + \ldots + H_n =1$.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Have you tried using induction on $n$?

Comment: No , I tried to write the sum like P(A|BH1)P(H1|B)+ P(A|BH2)P(H2|B)+ ...+P(A|BHn)P(Hn|B) = P(A|B)P(H1)P(H1|B)+...+P(A|B)P(H1)P(H1)P(B)=P(A|B)(P(H1)+...+P(Hn))=P(A|B)) But I am not sure can I just write P(B\Hi)=1 because Hi are independent events? Can you help ?

Comment: It looks like that after you cancel $P(B \cap H_i)$ from the numerator and denominator for $1 \leq i \leq n$ the numerator reduces to $$P(A \cap B \cap H_1) + P(A \cap B \cap H_2) + \cdots + P(A \cap B \cap H_n) = P(A \cap B \cap (H_1 \cup H_2 \cup \cdots H_n)) = P(A \cap B)$$ and the denominator reduces to $P(B)$.

Comment: Ok, than  I have P(AB)= P(A|B)P(B)P(B)... and can I just ake a conclusion that that equals P(A|B) because A depends of B and when is realised A|B ,then B had to be realised allready? I am really confused

Answer (score 0):

By definition, 
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} P(A|B \cap H_i)P(H_i|B) & = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{P(A \cap B \cap H_i)}{P(B \cap H_i)}\frac{P(B \cap H_i)}{P(B)}\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{P(A \cap B \cap H_i)}{P(B)}\\
& = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap H_1) + \cdots + P(A \cap B \cap H_n)}{P(B)}\\
& = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap \cup_{i = 1}^{n} H_i)}{P(B)}\\
& = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}\\
& = P(A|B)
\end{align*}
where we have used the assumption that $\cup_{i = 1}^{n} H_i$ is the universal set to conclude that $$A \cap B \cap \cup_{i = 1}^{n} H_i = A \cap B$$

Comment: You're welcome.  I realized induction would not work after I suggested it.  Your approach gave me the idea on how to finish the proof.